# Automatically determining Junit test side-effects

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-3, surefire

I have a set of legacy unit tests, most of which are Spring `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` tests, but some manage transactions on their own. Unfortunately, this seems to have introduced side-effects causing completely unrelated tests to fail when modifying the test data set, i.e., the failing test works when running it on its own (with the same initial data set), but fails when being run as part of the complete set of tests.

The tests are typically run through Maven's surefire plugin during the regular Maven build.

What I am looking for is an automated way to permute the amount and order of the executed tests to figure out the culprit. A naive, but pretty expensive approach, would take the power set of all tests and run all possible combinations. A more optimized approach would use the existing test execution order (which is mostly random, but stable) and test all potential ordered sub-sets. I am aware that the runtime of this process may be lengthy.

Are there any tools / Maven plugins that can do this out of the box?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but instead of relying on Spring-managed transactions and rollback (which fails in your situation) consider simply recreating the whole database before each test. Check out my [article](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/11/spring-pitfalls-transactional-tests.html).

Comment: Tomasz Nurkiewicz: That's what I would do when starting from scratch. Unfortunately, loading all required data takes ~ 20 s, which rules out this approach (I know that unit tests should should not rely on so much data, but when working with legacy code, one has to work with what is there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a tool which does specifically what you want, but you could play about with the [runOrder parameter in maven surefire](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder). From that page:

> Defines the order the tests will be run in. Supported values are
>   "alphabetical", "reversealphabetical", "random", "hourly"
>   (alphabetical on even hours, reverse alphabetical on odd hours),
>   "failedfirst", "balanced" and "filesystem".
>
> Odd/Even for hourly is
>   determined at the time the of scanning the classpath, meaning it could
>   change during a multi-module build.

So you could do a simple alphabetical runOrder and take the first failure, and start from there. At least you have a predictable run order. Then you run one by one (using -Dincludes) each test before the failing one & the failing one, to detect which one is making the failing test fail.

Then repeat the entire process for all of the failing tests. You could run this in a loop overnight or something.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply amend the tests to use a clean database copy each time? DBUnit is an excellent tool for doing this.

http://www.dbunit.org/

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Loading the data takes ~ 20 s, which is too costly for ~ 700 tests...

Comment: Fair enough - you could look at only loading the data you need for the specific test, but I'd reckon the analysis for that would take you as long as the way you're proposing, so there's no gain there.